# Use modulo to calculate period?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table in which I find how long it on average takes to complete a course (per course)

**StudentName | Course | TimetoCompleteCourse**

Johnny | French | 2 
Sean | English | 3 
Barbara | French | 8

Now I want to categorise that:

**Course | Avg TimeToComplete | Category**

French | 4 | 2-4 Months
English | 3 | 1-3 Months

As you see I want to categorise them in three month periods.
I do that know using a Case-statement but I feel this could be handled smarter, fe by using a mod 3 or something...

Any Ideas/ suggestions?

This is what I have now

```
        Category = CASE
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=3 THEN '1-3 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=4 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=6  THEN '4-6 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=7 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=9  THEN '7-9 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=10 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=12  THEN '10-12 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=13 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=15  THEN '13-15 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=16 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=18  THEN '16-18 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=19 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=21  THEN '18-21 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=22 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=24  THEN '22-24 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=25 AND avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) <=27  THEN '25-27 months'
            WHEN avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) >=28   THEN 'Way too long!'
        END
```

Comment: 'French | 4 | 2-4 Months' in your example should be 'French | 5 | 4-6 Months' right?

Comment: What you want is not what you show : do you want 2-4 Months for French, like in your example, or 4-6 Months, like in your sample code ?

Comment: I am very sorry, yes, I made a mistake, 'French | 4 | 2-4 Months' in your example should be 'French | 5 | 4-6 Months'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't want the modulus operator for this.  The mod operator will return the remainder from an integer division (11 mod 3 = 2).  Instead, I think you want to round to the nearest 3 month interval.  More specifically, take the average duration and round it to the nearest 3.

Try this:

```
Select  Course,
        Avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) As AvgTimeToComplete,
        Convert(VarChar(4), Ceiling(Avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) / 3.0) * 3 - 2)
        + ' - ' +
        Convert(VarChar(4), Ceiling(Avg(TimeToCompleteCourse) / 3.0) * 3)
        + ' Months' As Category
From    YourTableName
Group By Course
```

Note that I repeat the calculations where one of them has a -2 on it.  This is just to show the range of values.

Comment: +1 and for clarity, maintainability and re-use I'd consider extracting the 'month range' component into a scalar function.

Comment: Thanks, working on- and with suggestions from G Mastros and Kirk!

Answer (score 2):

This (although ugly) should do the trick for all modulo values:

```
select 
course
,CASE WHEN AVG(timetocompletecourse) > 27 THEN 'Way too long'
        WHEN AVG(timetocompletecourse) < 4 THEN '1-3 Months'
        WHEN AVG(timetocompletecourse)%3 = 0 THEN CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse)-2 AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Months'
        WHEN AVG(timetocompletecourse)%3 = 1 THEN CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse)+2 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Months'
        WHEN AVG(timetocompletecourse)%3 = 2 THEN CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse)-1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(AVG(timetocompletecourse)+1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Months'
        END as rangename
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 
course
```

Comment: I would remove studentname from the select and group by list, because it prevents averaging over all students for a course. Otherwise this seems to work just fine!